# C++ Visual Studio 2015 Google Tests Framework thru Resharper Breaking

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper, googletest

I have been using Google Tests that someone else put together for me and it has worked great...until today.  Now when I try to run a test I get a very mysterious problem and I am dead in the water.  I had the IT guys even recreate my profile which did have some issues etc - still the same error with little to go on:

[image: The message says that project has stopped working]

Any ideas?  Anything.  Dead in the water here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't try to run an individual unit test as I was doing, but simply press F5 from the testing framework (something I had never done actually as I always ran tests through the unit test framework) you can actually find a place where your program pukes.

My program was puking somewhere that had absolutely nothing to do with my unit test, so under the hood, it is clear that the framework needs to run and initialize a lot of stuff that has nothing to do with my tests - in this case it initialized an input stream from a file it could not find way outside of what I was doing.  Once I tracked that down, we were good again.

It was very counterintuitive that something so orthogonal to what I was doing caused this.  Resharper said they would try to give better error messages in the future.